# How to solve AngularJS encoding url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using AngularJS to build an app, there is a component called the `navbar` to store the searchbar with search() function.

```
$scope.search = function (keyword) {
      console.log(keyword);
      $state.go('main', {
        keyword: keyword
      }, {
        reload: true
      });

    };
```

And I have a problem with '/' encoding.

When I typed:

```
https://www.google.com
```

After the search function with `$state.go()`,

it turns into:

```
https:~2F~2Fwww.google.com
```

I want to know how to solve the problem, and if there is any more characters that with this kind of problem?? If so, please give a general way to solve it.

I have tried `decodeURI()` but there is no effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solve the question, the idea is to encode the keyword with `encodeURIComponent()` like what @RakeshChand said, but the keyword instead of URL, after sending the keyword which is encoded, and the AngularJS get the keyword by using the `$location.search().keyword`, and send back to the back-end express server. Then decode the keyword by using the `decodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use $location.search like as-

```
$scope.search = function (keyword) {
      console.log(keyword);
        $location.path('/main').search({keyword: keyword});


    };
```

Comment: The problem happened after $state.go(), before that, the keyword was okay to go

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent('url goes here')` while sending url, you don't need to use `decodeURI()`.

Comment: The problem happened after $state.go(), before that, the keyword was okay to go

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I have solved the problem with some changes, which is in my answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

this happens inside 'angular' not 'ngRoute' , angular forces encoding all urls using `encodeURICompenent`, 
so you need to change `encodeUriQuery` inside angular.js so it would pass the characters you want which is the front slash here

```
function encodeUriQuery(val, pctEncodeSpaces) {
  var r = /\//;
  if(r.test(val)){
    return val;
  }else{  
  return encodeURIComponent(val).
             replace(/@/gi, '@').
             replace(/:/gi, ':').
             replace(/$/g, '$').
             replace(/,/gi, ',').
             replace(/;/gi, ';').
             replace(/ /g, (pctEncodeSpaces ? ' ' : ' '));
  }
}
```

if you're using minified version or don't want to bother looking into code here is a monkey patch you can copy and paste this anywhere in your code

```
window.encode = window.encodeURIComponent;
window.encodeURIComponent = function(val){return /\//.test(val) ? val : window.encode(val)};
```